# What is the best method to get GNOME 2 in Arch Linux?

Tags: gnome, software-rec, arch-linux

I love Arch Linux, and I love Gnome 2, but it's no longer available, since now Gnome 3 is the default version.

I've seen MATE, which is a Gnome 2 Fork, and I've also seen that you can "rollback" your packages in Arch, so you can reinstall GNOME 2. Which of these works better?

Comment: Xfce is similar to GNOME 2 and uses GTK.  It's not quite the same but it could be worth checking out.

Comment: Gnome in fallback mode is similar to the previous version of gnome.

Answer (score 3):

As Arch is a rolling release, downgrading to Gnome2 is not really an option for any length of time as it neither a) fits well with the overall philosophy of Arch, or b) will be sustainable: it will eventually—and inevitably—lead to breakage as new packages and libraries are pushed to the repos.

Your best bet is to either go with Mate, or look at another window manager or desktop environment.

Comment: Yes, I though it was the worse option, I didn't want to do that, but I wanted some opinions, I'm going to try Mate but If I don't like it, I think that XFCE would be the best option, isn't it ?

Comment: XFCE is good. So is just running a WM like Openbox. The beauty of Arch is that you can do pretty much whatever you want with it...

Comment: I'm often trying WM like OpenBox or Xmonad, but I want a "stable" DE